# Change database in connectionstring from app

Tags: azure, xamarin

I have created a Xamarin where I want to query one database on a Azure SQL Server and regarding which result I get back I want to query one of X numbers of certain databases.

So far I have been able to create two different APIs where the first API gets information from the first database.

And I have hardcoded (in the TableController) to use one specific database (in the same SQL Server).

```
  string dbString = "database2";
  myContextClass context = new myContextClass(dbString);
```

This works like a charm. However. I would like to be able to pass which database I want to connect to from my app.

I.e. when calling my mobileservice all I do is this:

```
 this.client = new MobileServiceClient(
                Constants.DatabaseURL);
```

Is there something I can add to this methodcall that will set the database connectionstring in the controller?

Comment: Can you show relation between MobileServiceClient myContextClass. How you intiliaize your context. How your controllers reach context. Other than this it's hard to answer.

Comment: This is done via API to Azure. Used code generated by Azures API and FORM generation. So this is not something I have.

Comment: I'm not xmarian developer, but you shouldn't keep sensetive data in client(connection string is very sensetive). Beside of sending connection string you can create different controllers for each database. And in this controller constructors you intiliaze your context with specific connection strings.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel I have no static connection strings in the client. THe client fetches connection information from a server unique for each user. But thanks for the ehads up. I am able to initialize different dbStrings in the controller but I would like the client to send this dbString.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be connecting to the database from the mobile App, you should have a backend REST service built for example using Web API and hosted in Azure API Service, this is where the connection to the database will occur, and the connection string will be added to the web.config file which can be easily changed from the Azure portal.

Comment: Hence "So far I have been able to create two different APIs where the first API gets information from the first database. "
I would NEVER connect directly to the DB. What I want is to pass a string parameter from the client to the api. Perhaps via InvokeAsync or something?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, You should not specify the database name or connection string from the mobile app, if you want to get different information from differnt databases, then create two differnt methods.
Method1 get info from DB1 and Method2 get info from DB2

Always make the selection in the API.

If you must use a single method, then just pass a simple parameter, maybe an enum or integer and according to its value, select the appropriate database

Comment: And that's what I want help with. To pass a string or int to the API in the contructor of MobileServiceClient.

Comment: Why do you want to pass it to the MobileServiceClient? does it apply to all methods? or a specific method? if it is a specific method then pass the parameter to this method only.
Otherwise, you should have 2 APIs

Comment: *sigh* I want to pass a parameter to my API. Two APIs are out of the question. If you know how to do that please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 dbContext instances. Here is an example in the controller how to initialize 1 dbContext. So, I guess, you could have the parameter you want to specify which db you want, and use the main controller or call another controller which is initialized with the other dbContext. (or try overwriting the DomainManager with different context)

```
 public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            AppContext context = new AppContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request);
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
            return Query();
        }
```

Then you have 2 dbContext instances like this:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public NeptuneAppContext() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }
```

where you can specify different connectionStrings. 
Hope it helps

Comment: I went another way and use one api per context