# changing azure database connection string dynamically from xamarin mobile app

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin where I want to query one database on a Azure SQL Server and regarding which result I get back I want to query one of X numbers of certain databases.

We have developed xamarin.forms application with azure sync and it's working fine.
 Once we release the app, it may used by different users, so we have to create different databases for each user. So when an user is logged in, we have to read the corresponding database name(Connection string)for that user from one database and has to pass the value(database name/connection string) to the .Net Back-end for the syncing purpose.

i.e, I want to query one database on a Azure SQL Server and regarding the result I get back I want to query one of X numbers of certain databases.

How can we achieve this with Azure Offline Sync Service?
Or, shall we have to follow any other workaround?

Comment: Duplicate? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086284/change-database-in-connectionstring-from-app

Comment: @Joakim M,I checked the Link and Did you got any solution for your problem? If so can you please tell me, how can i do it?